# How to align <th> Header with <td> in Table?

Tags: html, jquery, datatables-1.10

Not able to align the header with the table data after enabling scrollbar(ScrollY) in the DataTable.
I have tried many solutions which are available online but it doesnt seem to be working.
I tried display:block but no luck.

Checkout the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/VM001/dzukjbh3/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Datatable:
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#TableName").Datatable( {
    language: { "search": "Filter"},
    paging: false,
    info: true,
    scrollY:'200px',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scrollX: false,
   });
});

<table id="TableName" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped>
<thead style="display:block">
<tr>
 <th>Item1</th>
 <th>Item2</th>
 <th>Item3</th>
 <th>Item4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for item in items_json %}
<tr>
 <td>{{ item.a }}</td>
<td>{{ item.b }}</td>
<td>{{ item.c }}</td>
<td>{{ item.d }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you share part of the code used to create the DataTable? It's difficult to figure out what's happening without an example of code.

Comment: hey i have updated the question with the code...let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: I think you need to add the CSS as well and maybe a screenshot or a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/VM001/dzukjbh3/

Comment: Have added jsfiddle here. Somehow scrollbar isnt coming up here but it is there is my webpage

Comment: @StuiterSlurf Please don't ask for external code representation if a StackOverflow snippet will just work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to remove some of your css rules but it seems working for me:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#P1SxTable").DataTable( {
    language: { "search": "Filter"},
    paging: false,
    info: true,
    scrollY:'50px',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scrollX: false,
   });
});
```

```css
/*table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}*/

th {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

table.table-bordered {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

/*thead {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
}*/
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Data</h2>
  <table id="P1SxTable" class ="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
    <!--caption><b>P1Sx YTD data</b></caption-->
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>Description </th>
        <th>Node Name</th>
        <th>Assignee</th>
        <th>Impact minutes</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>NumberXXXXX</td>
          <td>S1 </td>
          <td>Description size keeps on varying</td>
          <td>Node cisco123</td>
          <td>Network Operations</td>
          <td>Impact1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>NumberYYYYYY</td>
          <td>S3 </td>
          <td>Description again is very very very long</td>
          <td>Firewall Operations</td>
          <td>Assignee2</td>
          <td>Impact2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>NumberXXXXX</td>
          <td>S1 </td>
          <td>Description size keeps on varying</td>
          <td>Node cisco123</td>
          <td>Network Operations</td>
          <td>Impact1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>NumberYYYYYY</td>
          <td>S3 </td>
          <td>Description again is very very very very very very long</td>
          <td>Firewall Operations</td>
          <td>Assignee2</td>
          <td>Impact2</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberXXXXX</td>
            <td>S1 </td>
            <td>Description size keeps on varying</td>
            <td>Node cisco123</td>
            <td>Network Operations</td>
            <td>Impact1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberYYYYYY</td>
            <td>S3 </td>
            <td>Description again is very very very long</td>
            <td>Firewall Operations</td>
            <td>Assignee2</td>
            <td>Impact2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberXXXXX</td>
            <td>S1 </td>
            <td>Description size keeps on varying</td>
            <td>Node cisco123</td>
            <td>Network Operations</td>
            <td>Impact1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberYYYYYY</td>
            <td>S3 </td>
            <td>Description again is very very very long</td>
            <td>Firewall Operations</td>
            <td>Assignee2</td>
            <td>Impact2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberXXXXX</td>
            <td>S1 </td>
            <td>Description size keeps on varying</td>
            <td>Node cisco123</td>
            <td>Network Operations</td>
            <td>Impact1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberYYYYYY</td>
            <td>S3 </td>
            <td>Description again is very very very long</td>
            <td>Firewall Operations</td>
            <td>Assignee2</td>
            <td>Impact2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberXXXXX</td>
            <td>S1 </td>
            <td>Description size keeps on varying</td>
            <td>Node cisco123</td>
            <td>Network Operations</td>
            <td>Impact1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NumberYYYYYY</td>
            <td>S3 </td>
            <td>Description again is very very very long</td>
            <td>Firewall Operations</td>
            <td>Assignee2</td>
            <td>Impact2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```